# Machine readable HTML and CSS spec?

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a XML or JSON resource I can parse in Javascript that tells me what HTML elements there are, what their attributes are and what CSS styles I can apply? I want to have a list of valid options without typing in everything by hand.

Please bear with me here, I'm new to this web stuff but have plenty experience in C (mostly game engines).

TIA!

Comment: Can I ask, why do you need that?

Comment: Determining "valid" CSS styles for an element is going to be a pretty hard problem in general.

Comment: Need to create a HTML/CSS generator. Only for internal use, should be as generic as possible but doesn't have to be pretty (the code, I mean).

Comment: This is more complicated than you probably think.  HTML elements and their attributes have no true relationship to CSS beyond the default user agent style properties applied to them by browsers.  The valid properties for an element (and their effect on the layout) are largely determined by the value of other properties such as `display` and `position` and so forth.

Comment: Since the project is supposed to be quick and dirty, I thought I could auto-generate the UI from the HTML/CSS specs, as ugly as this will be. Now I feel I'm on the wrong track here. Thanks anyways everybody!

Answer (score 2):

(X)HTML before version 5 have DTDs that you can parse (you can get the URLs for them from the Doctype for the version of (X)HTML you are working with.

HTML 5 doesn't have an official machine readable spec. You might be able to extract something useful from [the validator.nu source code](http://about.validator.nu/#src) though.

The CSS properties that can be applied to an element depend only on what other CSS properties have bee applied to it. Their only connection to HTML is that the browser's default stylesheet applies some properties automatically.

Comment: Does that mean every CSS property is theoretically allowed for every HTML tag? Even if it doesn't have any effect on the display?

Comment: @user2983816 - pretty much, yes

Comment: @user2983816 — Yes. For example `width` applies to *all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row groups*, so doesn't apply to `<span>` … until someone does something like `span { display: block; }`. All the CSS "applies to" rules are like that. They are only limited by the other rules applied to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this answer is almost six years too late for you. I was looking for the same thing and ended up writing my own tool for extracting some of the specs from the standard and exporting it as JSON

https://github.com/tawesoft/html5spec (self promotion disclaimer: I made this)

Hope that helps someone